# Cherry-picking from github: pick only the commit's new code

Tags: android, git, cherry-pick

When I do cherry-pick from github, it usually adds code that is not from the commit, but that I don't have in my files.

Is there any way to tell cherry-pick to only add the code that is new from the commit I want to cherry-pick?

Comment: That's what cherry-pick already does. From the manual: *Given one or more existing commits, apply the change each one introduces, recording a new commit for each.* What exactly are you trying to achieve? From git's perspective everything you are trying to cherry-pick is 'code that is new'.

Comment: Can you add to your question the exact commands you're using and the output you have ? It will clarify the question and help you get a relevant answer.